# Adapter for class extend class

Tags: java, android

I have class object Student, Teacher, Worker extends class object People. Now, I want to write one adapter which can be used for all classes. I have tried using the ArrayAdapter `<People>` but when passing to the Student array the error occurred.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJIzK.png)

```
public class AdapterPeople extends ArrayAdapter<People> {
private ArrayList<People> arrPeople;
private Context context;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

public AdapterPeople(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull ArrayList<People> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    this.arrPeople = objects;
    this.context = context;
    this.layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
```

Comment: Please show what error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ArrayList<People>` is not same as `ArrayList<Student>`

so you can use wild card `?`

```
public class AdapterPeople extends ArrayAdapter<People> {
    private ArrayList<? extends People> arrPeople;
    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public AdapterPeople(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull ArrayList<? extends People> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.arrPeople = objects;
        this.context = context;
        this.layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
```

Proof

[**Generics, Inheritance, and Subtypes**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html)

Solution Reference

[**Upper Bounded Wildcards**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html)

Comment: i am glad that i could help, happy coding